# itunes connect bank account with a different name

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

My girlfriend opened an individual developer account with her name because i don't have a credit card;

i wonder if i can put my bank account in the "bank info" in itunes connect with my name or that will be a problem note that the account is of type individual and supposed to be only one owner.

thanks